# Create ServiceMonitor in Prometheus Operator

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am new to Kubernetes. I want to create Service Monitor in Prometheus Operator. I've installed Prometheus Operator and Grafana. I have the running pods as shown below:
[image]

The [documentation of Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#include-servicemonitors) provides code below to create Service Monitor.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: frontend
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  enableAdminAPI: false
```

I know this is a yaml file, but I am confused how to run this file? In other words, where should I put this piece of code to? I am learning to create Prometheus monitors. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy it like any other manifest in Kubernetes cluster, for example by running `kubectl apply -f servicemonitor.yaml`.

You can check if it was deployed by simply running `kubectl get prometheus`:

```
$ kubectl get prometheus
NAME         VERSION   REPLICAS   AGE
prometheus                        5s
```

When you enabled RBAC authorization there is another yaml that you should use:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    prometheus: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 2
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: frontend
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - namespace: default
      name: alertmanager
      port: web
```